# Custom Payload is not working for Messenger

Tags: facebook-messenger, dialogflow-es, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-chatbot

I am trying to add suggestion chips in dialog flow to be used in Facebook Messenger. But it is not Working which i am unable to understand

Here is my Custom Payload

```
{
  "facebook": {
    "attachment": {
      "type": "suggestion_chips",
        "title": "title",
      "suggestions": [  "chip 1" ," chip 2"]
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you show the code that constructs your entire request?

Comment: Hi there, I didn't use any code(just using the dialog flow for everything). I resolve that by using quick replies instead of suggestion ship.

Comment: Yep, in the Dialogflow UI you should just use Quick Replies: https://dialogflow.com/docs/intents/rich-messages#quick_replies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Facebook Messenger [Custom payload](https://dialogflow.com/docs/intents/rich-messages#custom_payload) can only use to integrate Audio Video and File. Not for the suggestion chips.

Alternatively, We can use messenger [Quick replies](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/quick-replies) as Suggested answers.